# Create an Store Procedure for Insert-Update in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to insert or update a record based on an input variable. But when I try to compile the SP simply tells me the following: Code 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the Manual That Corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'' at line 80. And I have not found the solution. Thank you very much for any help you can give me.

My SP code is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_sertup`(IN i_operation CHAR(1),
                        IN i_system VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_subsystem VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_ref VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_significance VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_rank VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_implication VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_loc1 VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_loc2 VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_task VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_time VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_cost1 VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_cost2 VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_note VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_attach VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_operation_text VARCHAR(20),
                        IN i_id_setup INT )

BEGIN
    IF  (i_operation = 'I') THEN
        UPDATE setup_gs SET setup_status  = 0 WHERE id_setup = id_setup; 

            INSERT INTO setup_gs(
                SystemLabel,
                SubsystemLabel,
                RefLabel,
                SignificanceLabel,
                RankLabel,
                ImplicationLabel,
                Location1Label,
                Location2Label,
                TaskLabel,
                TimeLabel,
                Cost1Label,
                Cost2Label,
                NoteLabel,
                attachmentText,
                OperationsText,
                setup_status
            ) 
            VALUES 
            (
                i_system,
                i_subsystem,
                i_ref,
                i_significance,
                i_rank,
                i_implication,
                i_loc1,
                i_loc2,
                i_task,
                i_time,
                i_cost1,
                i_cost2,
                i_note,
                i_attach,
                i_operation_text,
                1);

    IF (i_operation = 'U') THEN
        UPDATE
            setup_gs
        SET
            SystemLabel        = values(i_system),
            SubsystemLabel     = values(i_subsystem),
            RefLabel           = values(i_ref),
            SignificanceLabel  = values(i_significance),
            RankLabel          = values(i_rank),
            ImplicationLabel   = values(i_implication),
            Location1Label     = values(i_loc1),
            Location2Label     = values(i_loc2),
            TaskLabel          = values(i_task),
            TimeLabel          = values(i_time),
            Cost1Label         = values(i_cost1),
            Cost2Label         = values(i_cost2),
            NoteLabel          = values(i_note),
            attachmentText     = values(i_attach),
            OperationsText     = values(i_operation_text),
            setup_status       = 1
        WHERE id_setup           = i_id_setup;          
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must finish your [`IF`-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) with `END IF` in MySQL.

Also, one of your tests is between id_setup and id_setup. It should be between id_setup and i_id_setup.

Comment: Wao, that simple, thank you very much, worked perfectly. I had hours hanging around with this. You saved me on Saturday!

Comment: NP and welcome to SO! Remember to up vote any answer you like and to check the mark for accepted answer on the best one if you agree on it.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create a update stored procedure then follow these steps in mysql command line. it is work perfectly.

```
create procedure procedure_name(id int, name varchar(40),salary float)
                        update table_name set name=name,salary=salary from id=id;
```

firstly you need to create a table. after that write the keyword `create procedure` and after that write `procedure_name()` inside the procedure function write the column name.

i took `id`, `name`, `salary` inside the procedure and also provide the type of all after that i wrote simple query that is `update table_NAME set name=name, salary=salary where id=id` . because i want to change the name and salary of this id. now you use.